# Processing saving to .txt file?

Tags: java, file, printing, output, processing

I dont know how to save to a txt file in processing, i have tried some different things, but every time it seems like the file is overridden because of:

```
output = createWriter("positions.txt");
```

If i try to remove this line, or try something else to check if the file insist and then dont run the line, i a NullPointerException.

Is there any way to save a file without the file getting overridden?

```
PrintWriter output;

void setup() {
  // Create a new file in the sketch directory
  output = createWriter("positions.txt"); 
}

void draw() {
  point(mouseX, mouseY);
  output.println(mouseX);  // Write the coordinate to the file
}

void keyPressed() {
  output.flush();  // Writes the remaining data to the file
  output.close();  // Finishes the file
  exit();  // Stops the program
}
```

Comment: The file is being overwritten because you're using the same path `"positions.txt"`. If you want to create a new file each time, loop through numbers using a `while` or `for` loop to check if `"positions" + number + ".txt"` exists. Keep going until a file doesn't exist and use that as your path.

Comment: @khelwood This is processing not Java - createWriter is a native function to Processing. And with that in mind, op - Processing != Java, so worth removing the Java tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you've noticed, Processing's `createWriter()` function creates a new file every time it's called.

If you google "Processing append to text file" or "Java append to text file" you'll get a ton of results.

Basically, you want to use Java's `PrintWriter` class, whose constructor takes a `boolean` argument. If that argument is `true`, your data will be appended to the end of the file instead of overwriting the original.